# How to implement CRC32 taking advantage of Intel specific instructions?

Tags: c, crc32

Intel has a specific [`CRC32` instruction](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/8/b/8/D9156103.pdf) available in the SSE4.2 instruction set. How can I take advantage of this instruction to speed up CRC32 calculations?