# Have GAS generate instruction from inline assembly?

Tags: gcc, inline-assembly, gnu-assembler, arm64

I'm trying to assemble a file that uses ARM's CRC instruction. The assembler is producing an error *`Error: selected processor does not support 'crc32b w1,w0,w0'`*.

There are runtime checks in place, so we are safe with the instruction. The technique works fine on i686 and x86_64. For example, I can assemble a file that uses Intel [CRC intrinsics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31184201/608639) or [SHA Intrinsics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21107350/608639) without `-mcrc` or `-msha` (and on a machine without the features).

Here is the test case:

```
$ cat test.cxx
#include <arm_neon.h>

#define GCC_INLINE_ATTRIB __attribute__((__gnu_inline__, __always_inline__, __artificial__))

#if defined(__GNUC__) && !defined(__ARM_FEATURE_CRC32)
__inline unsigned int GCC_INLINE_ATTRIB
CRC32B(unsigned int crc, unsigned char v)
{
  unsigned int r;
  asm ("crc32b %w2, %w1, %w0" : "=r"(r) : "r"(crc), "r"((unsigned int)v));
  return r;
}
#else
  // Use the intrinsic
# define CRC32B(a,b) __crc32b(a,b)
#endif

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  return CRC32B(argc, argc);
}
```

And here is the result:

```
$ g++ test.cxx -c
/tmp/ccqHBPUf.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccqHBPUf.s:23: Error: selected processor does not support `crc32b w1,w0,w0'
```

Placing the ASM code in a source file and compiling with different options is not feasible because `CRC32B` will be used in C++ header files, too.

How do I get GAS to assemble the instruction?

---

GCC's configuration and options are the reason we are trying to do things this way. User's don't read manuals, so they won't add `-march=armv8-a+crc+crypto -mtune=cortex-a53` to `CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS`.

In addition, distros compile to a "least capable" machine, so we want the hardware acceleration routines available. When the library is provided by a distro like Linaro, both code paths (software CRC and hardware accelerated CRC) will be available.

---

The machine is a LeMaker HiKey, which is ARMv8/Aarch64. It has an A53 processor with CRC and Crypto (CRC and Crypto is optional under the architecture):

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
Processor       : AArch64 Processor rev 3 (aarch64)
processor       : 0
...
processor       : 7
Features        : fp asimd evtstrm aes pmull sha1 sha2 crc32
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: AArch64
```

GCC lacks most of the usual defines one expects to be present by default:

```
$ g++ -dM -E - </dev/null | sort | egrep -i '(arm|neon|aarch|asimd)'
#define __aarch64__ 1
#define __AARCH64_CMODEL_SMALL__ 1
#define __AARCH64EL__ 1
```

Using GCC's `-march=native` does not work on ARM:

```
$ g++ -march=native -dM -E - </dev/null | sort | egrep -i '(arm|neon|aarch|asimd)'
cc1: error: unknown value ‘native’ for -march
```

And Clang:

```
$ clang++ -dM -E - </dev/null | sort | egrep -i '(arm|neon|aarch|asimd)'
#define __AARCH64EL__ 1
#define __ARM_64BIT_STATE 1
#define __ARM_ACLE 200
#define __ARM_ALIGN_MAX_STACK_PWR 4
#define __ARM_ARCH 8
#define __ARM_ARCH_ISA_A64 1
#define __ARM_ARCH_PROFILE 'A'
#define __ARM_FEATURE_CLZ 1
#define __ARM_FEATURE_DIV 1
#define __ARM_FEATURE_FMA 1
#define __ARM_FEATURE_UNALIGNED 1
#define __ARM_FP 0xe
#define __ARM_FP16_FORMAT_IEEE 1
#define __ARM_FP_FENV_ROUNDING 1
#define __ARM_NEON 1
#define __ARM_NEON_FP 0xe
#define __ARM_PCS_AAPCS64 1
#define __ARM_SIZEOF_MINIMAL_ENUM 4
#define __ARM_SIZEOF_WCHAR_T 4
#define __aarch64__ 1
```

---

GCC version:

```
$ gcc -v
...
gcc version 4.9.2 (Debian/Linaro 4.9.2-10)
```

GAS version:

```
$ as -v
GNU assembler version 2.24 (aarch64-linux-gnu) using BFD version (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.24
```

Comment: I don't have an environment to test this, but it sounds like what you need is `.arch_extension name`.  Perhaps added directly to this asm instruction.  According to the [docs](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/ARM-Directives.html), this allows you to *add or remove extensions incrementally to the architecture being compiled for*.  Failing that, perhaps adding an `.arch name` as a "top level" bit of 'basic' asm?

Comment: Or are there more constraints here that I'm missing?  Adding directives to asm instructions like this is nothing new.  People have been using it to put intel-style assembler into asm instructions since forever.

Comment: @David - Thanks. I thought along the same lines. Alas, A-32, Aarch32 and Aarch64 are not IA32. I tried `.arch_extension` yesterday, but it resulted in errors. `.arch_extension` needs Binutils 2.26 from 2016. 2.26 has the support for both Aarch32 and Aarch64. Also see [Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.arch_extension'](https://lists.linaro.org/pipermail/linaro-toolchain/2017-April/006112.html) on the Linaro Toolchain mailing list.

Comment: Sounds like `#pragma GCC target` is going to be a better bet than using (a potentially conflicting) `.arch` asm at file scope.  Something to keep in mind though.

Comment: @David - Thanks. `#pragma GCC target` needs GCC 6 for Aarch64. And a correction: Binutils 2.26 is from 2014; not 2016.

Answer (score 2):

This answer came from Jiong Wang on the [Binutils mailing list](https://sourceware.org/ml/binutils/2017-04/msg00171.html). It bypasses GAS's architectural requirements and plays well with GCC:

```c
__inline unsigned int GCC_INLINE_ATTRIB
CRC32W(unsigned int crc, unsigned int val)
{
#if 1
    volatile unsigned int res;
    asm ("\n"
         "\t" ".set reg_x0, 0\n"
         "\t" ".set reg_x1, 1\n"
         "\t" ".set reg_x2, 2\n"
         "\t" ".set reg_x3, 3\n"
         "\t" ".set reg_x4, 4\n"
         "\t" ".set reg_x5, 5\n"
         "\t" ".set reg_x6, 6\n"
         "\t" ".set reg_x7, 7\n"
         "\t" "#crc32w %w0, %w1, %w2\n"
         "\t" ".inst 0x1ac04800 | (reg_%2 << 16) | (reg_%1 << 5) | (reg_%0)\n"
         : "=r"(res) : "r"(crc), "r"(val)
    );
    return res;
#else
    volatile unsigned int res;
    asm (".cpu generic+fp+simd+crc+crypto  \n"
         "crc32w %w0, %w1, %w2             \n"
         : "=r"(res) : "r"(crc), "r"(val));
    return res;
#endif
}
```

The second one commented out by the preprocessor block was suggested by Nick Clifton on the [Binutils mailing list](https://sourceware.org/ml/binutils/2017-04/msg00174.html). The idea is GCC generates code using the ISA based on `-march=XXX`, so it does not matter if we increase capabilities to get past the assembler. We decided to go with Wang's answer because we did not want potential side effects from modifying the `.cpu`.

And the verification with GCC 4.8 and Binutils 2.24:

```
$ g++ -O1 test.cxx -c

$ objdump --disassemble test.o

test.o:     file format elf64-littleaarch64

Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <main>:
   0:   12001c01        and     w1, w0, #0xff
   4:   1ac14800        crc32w  w0, w0, w1
   8:   d65f03c0        ret
```